# Cursor Instance Error when connecting to mongo db?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I have a web application that uses flask and mongodb. I recently downloaded a clone of it from github onto a new Linux machine, then proceeded to run it. It starts and runs without any errors, but when I use a function that needs access to the database, I get this error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 533,  in __ getitem__
>        raise IndexError("no such item for Cursor instance")
>    IndexError: no such item for Cursor instance

This isn't happening on any of the other computers running this same application. Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it ended up being an issue with the String specifying the working directory. Once it was resolved I was able to connect to the database.